# Rails 3: Database column won't update through active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I haven't an issue where I can't seem to update or modify a database column in rails 3. I've never seen anything like this before and as such am sure it's something small that I'm overlooking. Please help!

IRB Output:

```
    ruby-1.9.2-p318 :002 > User.all
      User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
     => [] 
    ruby-1.9.2-p318 :003 > User.create( :login => "dummy", :password => "foobar", :password_
    confirmation => "foobar", :role => "user", :email => "dummy@email.com" )
       (0.1ms)  begin transaction
      User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."login" = 'dummy' LIMIT 1
      User Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'dummy@email.com' L
    IMIT 1
      SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "hashed_password", "login", "
    role", "salt", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 05 Apr 2
    012 02:21:00 UTC +00:00], ["email", "dummy@email.com"], ["hashed_password", "6416111c47f
    a52ddfbde9e539ee6e369807bdeab"], ["login", "dummy"], ["role", nil], ["salt", "1LTzevgRHt
    "], ["updated_at", Thu, 05 Apr 2012 02:21:00 UTC +00:00]]
       (61.5ms)  commit transaction
     => #<User id: 3, login: "dummy", role: nil, hashed_password: "6416111c47fa52ddfbde9e539
    ee6e369807bdeab", email: "dummy@email.com", salt: "1LTzevgRHt", created_at: "2012-04-05 
    02:21:00", updated_at: "2012-04-05 02:21:00"> 
    ruby-1.9.2-p318 :004 > u = User.first
      User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
     => #<User id: 3, login: "dummy", role: nil, hashed_password: "6416111c47fa52ddfbde9e539
    ee6e369807bdeab", email: "dummy@email.com", salt: "1LTzevgRHt", created_at: "2012-04-05 
    02:21:00", updated_at: "2012-04-05 02:21:00"> 
    ruby-1.9.2-p318 :005 > u.role 
     => nil 
    ruby-1.9.2-p318 :006 > u.role = "foo"
     => "foo" 
    ruby-1.9.2-p318 :007 > u.role
     => "foo" 
    ruby-1.9.2-p318 :008 > u
     => #<User id: 3, login: "dummy", role: nil, hashed_password: "6416111c47fa52ddfbde9e539
    ee6e369807bdeab", email: "dummy@email.com", salt: "1LTzevgRHt", created_at: "2012-04-05 
    02:21:00", updated_at: "2012-04-05 02:21:00">
```

Migration:

```
    class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :users do |t|
          t.column :login, :string
          t.column :role, :string
          t.column :hashed_password, :string
          t.column :email, :string
          t.column :salt, :string
          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

Schema:

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120318205424) do

      create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "login"
        t.string   "role"
        t.string   "hashed_password"
        t.string   "email"
        t.string   "salt"
        t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
      end

    end
```

Model:

```
    require 'digest/sha1'
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates_length_of :login, :within => 3..40
      validates_length_of :password, :within => 4..40
      validates_presence_of :login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :salt
      validates_uniqueness_of :login, :email
      validates_confirmation_of :password
      validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i, :message => "Invalid email"  

      attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation, :role
      attr_protected :id, :salt

      def self.random_string(len)
        chars = ("a".."z").to_a + ("A".."Z").to_a + ("0".."9").to_a
        newpass = ""
        1.upto(len) { |i| newpass << chars[rand(chars.size-1)] }
        return newpass
      end

      def password=(pass)
        @password=pass
        self.salt = User.random_string(10) if !self.salt?
        self.hashed_password = User.encrypt(@password, self.salt)
      end

      def self.encrypt(pass, salt)
        Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{pass}#{salt}")
      end

      def self.authenticate(login, pass)
        u=find(:first, :conditions=>["login = ?", login])
        return nil if u.nil?
        if User.encrypt(pass, u.salt)==u.hashed_password
          # edits wont save without this
          u.password=u.password_confirmation=pass
          return u
        end
        nil
      end

      def send_new_password
        new_pass = User.random_string(10)
        self.password = self.password_confirmation = new_pass
        self.save
        Notification.deliver_forgot_password(self.email, self.login, new_pass)
      end

      def admin?
        (self.role == "admin")
      end

    end
```

SQLite Update, to show it works:

```
    sqlite> select * from users;
    3|dummy||6416111c47fa52ddfbde9e539ee6e369807bdeab|dummy@email.com|1LTzevgRHt|2012-04-05 02:21:00.752890|2012-04-05 02:21:00.752890
    sqlite> select role from users;

    sqlite> select role from users where login = "dummy";

    sqlite> update users set role = "user" where login = "dummy";
    sqlite> select role from users where login = "dummy";
    user
    sqlite> select * from users;
    3|dummy|user|6416111c47fa52ddfbde9e539ee6e369807bdeab|dummy@email.com|1LTzevgRHt|2012-04-05 02:21:00.752890|2012-04-05 02:21:00.752890
```

I've been messing with this for a while... thanks for any help you can give.

EDIT on request:

```
    ruby-1.9.2-p318 :011 > User.last.update_attributes!(:role => "foo") 
      User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
       (0.1ms)  begin transaction
      User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."login" = 'dummy' AND "users"."id" != 3) LIMIT 1
      User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'dummy@email.com' AND "users"."id" != 3) LIMIT 1
       (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
    ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password is too short (minimum is 4 characters), Password can't be blank, Password confirmation can't be blank
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:33:in `save!'
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:246:in `block in save!'
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:246:in `save!'
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:224:in `block in update_attributes!'
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:222:in `update_attributes!'
            from (irb):11
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
            from /home/jmervine/Development/personal/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
            from script/rails:6:in `require'
            from script/rails:6:in `<main>'ruby-1.9.2-p318 :012 > User.last.update_attributes!(:role => "foo")
```

Comment: can you paste the output of `User.last.update_attributes!(:role => "foo")`

Comment: I've added it. Note I've tried ensuring that password and password_confirmation are are meeting the validation requirements. I'm pretty sure that's not the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove `:role` from this line `attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation, :role`

Comment: When you add `:role` to your schema, ActiveRecord knows that when you say `user.role`, it should read from the `@attributes` hash which is populated when the user is read from the database, and also when you assign to `user.role`, it should write to the `@attributes` hash. Essentially, ActiveRecord is creating #role and #role= methods for you to do this. So two things: 1) By saying `attr_accessor :role`, you overrode these methods. 2) The `@attributes` hash is read from when you say `user.inspect`, so that's why your changes appeared not to take effect.

Comment: When you define `role` as accessor, it's override reader and writer methods of AR